# Where clause specification not working with fulltext search query

Tags: php, sql, full-text-search

**Context**

I just added the FULLTEXT index onto a few columns between two separate tables. The actual fulltext implementation works fine; however, when I use the `MATCH() AGAINST()` in the WHERE clause, my other specification in the WHERE clause fails to work. My query goes like so:

```
SELECT 
articles.article_id, 
articles.title, 
articles.article, 
articles.idUsers,
articles.published,
users.uidUsers, 
MATCH(articles.title, articles.article) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS content, 
MATCH(users.uidUsers) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS user, 
articlecoverimages.image, 
profileimages.image AS profileImage 
FROM 
articles 
JOIN users 
JOIN articlecoverimages 
JOIN profileimages 
ON users.idUsers = articlecoverimages.idUsers 
AND 
articles.article_id = articlecoverimages.article_id 
AND 
profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers 
WHERE //start of the code in question
MATCH(articles.title, articles.article) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR 
MATCH(users.uidUsers) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND
articles.published = ? //end of the code in question
ORDER BY
(content + user) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

This query works fine except for one thing: despite that fact that I specified that the variable used with

```
...
AND
articles.published = ? 
...
```

is ? = "yes", the query still returns rows where `articles.published` is equal to "no". Everything else about the query is fine and works well; the articles are ordered by relevance of text and username.

**Question**

Is there a rule where you can't specify anything in the WHERE clause when using FULLTEXT or something of that sort? If not, is there anything visibly wrong with my code?

**What I've Tried**

I have already tried changing the order of the `articles.published = ?` to before and after the
`MATCH` specifications in the WHERE clause to no avail. Let me know if there's something else I could put on here to make this easier to understand or if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: You need `()` around `MATCH(articles.title, articles.article) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(users.uidUsers) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)` to make the logic in your `WHERE` clause correct.

Comment: @Nick that makes sense. It worked perfectly. Thanks.